# Как вывести все минимальные значения из БД в php?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. В моей таблице есть колонка с ценами на товар.
Есть 5 товаров по цене:

1. 20
2. 30
3. 20
4. 90
5. 150

Мне нужно вывести все товары с минимальной ценой, в данном случае "20". То есть товары 1 и 3. Я пробую делать так:

```
$tov = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT MIN(`price`) as min FROM `dress` WHERE `color` like '%blue%' and `size` = '52'");
```

Далее пробую всё это зациклить:

```
while ($prices = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tov))
{
    echo prices['min'];
}
```

Но мне выводится только цена первого товара. То есть "20" должно выводиться 2 раза, а выводится только 1. Как сделать, чтобы вывелись цены сразу всех товаров с минимальной стоимостью?

p.s.

Понимаю, что вопрос для новичков. И понимаю, что в данном контексте непонятно зачем мне это нужно. Но если, к примеру, есть несколько товаров одной категории и одного размера, но разного цвета, тогда нужна возможность делать именно такой вывод

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    `dress`
WHERE 
    price = (SELECT MIN(`price`) FROM `dress` WHERE `color` LIKE '%blue%' AND `size` = '52')
    AND 
    `color` LIKE '%blue%' 
    AND 
    `size` = '52'
```

Возможно, условия на `color` и `size` можно не повторять.

Comment: сработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так, но сомневаюсь, что это правильно... Есть ли другие решения?

```
$min_price = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tov)['min']

$tov = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `dress` WHERE `color` like '%blue%' and `size` = '52' and `price` = $min_price");
```

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: это можно считать за ответ. Так всё работает. Но код очень нагромождается. Хотел бы сделать проще, если такое возможно